# Xcode 8: changing team causes error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, provisioning-profile, signing

I have an iOS project developed using Xcode 8. The development was going on all right, but now for some reason I have to change the team, and then I encounter this error:

[image]

It looks like that my app ID is stuck with my old team. But I have to switch to a new team, and I cannot change the app ID. What can I do to fix this? I tried to remove this app ID from the old team, but when I checked the app ID list on the old team's Apple Developer web page I couldn't find that app ID there.